# Why does this derived class behave different from it's base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, mono, gtk#

In some obscure way a derived class which doesn't add new functionality (yet) behaves different from it's base class. The derived class:

```
public class MyCheckButton : CheckButton
{
    public MyCheckButton(string label) : base(label)
    {
    }
}
```

MyCheckButton inherits from a (GTK#, part of the Mono project) CheckButton. However in the following code snippet they behave differently:

```
var button1 = new CheckButton("_foo");
var button2 = new MyCheckButton("_foo");
// code omitted
```

The underscore in the label makes sure that the label gets a mnemonic. For button1 this works in my testcode: I get "foo" where the f is underlined. However for button2 this fails. I just get "_foo" as a label in my dialog.

Can anyone explain how the derived class in this example could behave differently or is there some magic going on behind the screen that maybe checks the type of the actual class?

Comment: Is this code of MyCheckButton is all presented here?

Comment: What if you don't add button1? Perhaps it doesn't like two 'f' mnemonics?

Comment: Yes, this is all the code. I made the example as simple as possible. The two same mnemonics are not the problem. I've tried that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [I]s there some magic going on behind the screen that maybe checks the
>   type of the actual class?

Actually, there is:

```
public CheckButton(string label) : base(IntPtr.Zero)
{
    if (base.GetType() != typeof(CheckButton))
    {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList arrayList2 = new ArrayList();
        arrayList2.Add("label");
        arrayList.Add(new Value(label));
        this.CreateNativeObject((string[])arrayList2.ToArray(typeof(string)), (Value[])arrayList.ToArray(typeof(Value)));
    }
    else
    {
        IntPtr intPtr = Marshaller.StringToPtrGStrdup(label);
        this.Raw = CheckButton.gtk_check_button_new_with_mnemonic(intPtr);
        Marshaller.Free(intPtr);
    }
}
```

It looks like your subclass will be going the former route. Not sure why that would mess up the mnemonic, though; the latter method is a P/Invoke on the native gtk library. It's possible that wrapping `label` in a `Value` object is mucking up the mnemonic stuff.

Let that be a lesson (to the GTK# designers): don't violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). It's confusing!

Comment: The mnemonic disappears in the former route because the button's "use-underline" property is not set to True, as it is in the native `gtk_check_button_new_with_mnemonic()` constructor. A "use-underline", True pair should be added to the array lists. This is not a deliberate violation of the substitution principle, it's a bug and should be reported at http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs .

Answer (score 2):

Here's why, look at the source for the CheckButton ctor:

```
public CheckMenuItem (string label) : base (IntPtr.Zero)
{
    if (GetType() != typeof (CheckMenuItem)) {
        CreateNativeObject (new string [0], new GLib.Value [0]);
        AccelLabel al = new AccelLabel ("");
        al.TextWithMnemonic = label;
        al.SetAlignment (0.0f, 0.5f);
        Add (al);
        al.AccelWidget = this;
        return;
    }

    IntPtr native = GLib.Marshaller.StringToPtrGStrdup (label);
    Raw = gtk_check_menu_item_new_with_mnemonic (native);
    GLib.Marshaller.Free (native);
}
```

Derived types do not follow the same code path as CheckButton in the .ctor